# Installing Ubuntu 20.04 on an external SSD for a machine that only has legacy BIOS

Tags: boot, partitioning, external-hdd

I am very new to Linux and am trying to install Ubuntu 20.04 on an external SSD so that I could run both Windows and Linux without dual-booting. My machine can only run legacy BIOS.

My internal hard disk is MBR while the live USB and external SSD are GPT.

When partitioning the external SSD, I put only `\` and `swap`, but it gave me a warning saying "No EFI partition found".

Quite stuck at this point and I really don't want to mess up my existing Windows OS. Removing the internal hard drive is also not an option since I lack the expertise to do that.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: See https://superuser.com/questions/1337344/is-it-possible-to-boot-linux-from-a-gpt-disk-on-a-bios-system

Comment: Hope this [site](https://www.58bits.com/blog/2020/02/28/how-create-truly-portable-ubuntu-installation-external-usb-hdd-or-ssd) helps

Comment: What brand/model system? I have used gpt with BIOS back in 2010. When Windows started requiring UEFI, I used gpt but had both ESP - efi system partiiton (FAT32) and unformatted 1MB bios_grub partition on every new or changed drive, so I could convert to UEFI easily. You just have to boot installer in BIOS mode and use Something Else so you can choose to install grub to external drive (does not work withUEFI install). It does seem new installer wants an ESP no matter what, so just make one, does not have to be large 100MB ok, if for future use and one or two systems to boot.